# Why does frequency of a wave depend solely on its wavelength?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength, speed

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) it was stated that a wave's speed $v$, wavelength $\lambda$ and frequency $f$ are related by the identity
$$v(\lambda)=\lambda f(\lambda).$$

The function $f(\lambda)$ tells us that the frequency of a wave depend solely on its wavelength. Why is that so?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "why is that so"? Like you presented the question this seems a mathematical issue you have:When the lefthand side is a certain function f(x) the righthand side has to be also a function of x, so lets call it g(x). If this is not true, lets say g would instead depend on "y" (so: g(y)) then f and g would be constant automatically (with respect to x and w.r.t. y). Or mathematically $f(x)=g(y)\Rightarrow f(x)=g(y) = const.$

Comment: @hagebutte I am asking why the frequency of a wave depend solely on its wavelength.

Comment: Ye thats not really sufficient for me what your thought process is to arrive there. For example: Do you have any other parameter in mind and you wonder why its not dependent on them? One could even say the answer to your question is the above formula. Different people mean different things when saying "why is this and that". The blank statement "frequency of a wave depend solely on its wavelength" is of course false. It depends also on a lot of other, e.g. postion, material...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh this is a fun question. It took me a few readings to “get” it though.

## The basic relation: $v(f, t)$

So if we were to actually reconstruct what is happening from first principles, we would probably instead say something like this: “Dispersion is when the speed of a wave through some medium depends on its frequency, $v = v(f)$ where $f$ is the frequency of the wave.” There is no mention here of wavelength because wavelength is a derived phenomenon: when you are standing somewhere and a wave washes over you with speed $v$ and frequency $f$, then that frequency means that the waves have a period $T = 1/f$ and the length of the wave is then $v T = v(f)/f$. Note that this would also be a function of frequency, $\lambda(f) = v(f) / f.$

Other variables could certainly enter into this function $v(f)$, for example maybe the temperature of the medium makes a difference. Or maybe, like the oceans and the atmosphere, they are more dense the lower you go and this affects the speed of sound, too. If we wanted to incorporate them maybe the easiest general approach would be to add a time dependence, so we tell our grad students “please tell me how the temperature varies over time and then how this affects the dispersion, please give me a $v(f, t)$, and I will use that.” But the point here is that if I am just explaining dispersion to you, let me assume that this dispersion relation $v(f)$ is **not** changing over time, so that I do not have to deal with such a headache! And this means that we are left with just one function of one parameter, $v(f)$ or if you’d prefer, $\lambda(f).$

Note that the frequency is in many ways objectively better as a variable to use than the wavelength. For example, at the interface between two different media, causality forces wavefronts to not enter one medium more rapidly than they exit the other medium, so frequency is constant across the boundary and the entire velocity shift is absorbed into a lengthening or shortening of the wavelength.

## But that's not how we write dispersion relations?

Now let me explain why everybody prefers to instead write the dispersion relation as $\omega(k)$ where $k = 2\pi/\lambda$ and $\omega = 2\pi f.$ Note that this requires that the above $\lambda(f)$ be an invertible function so that we can define $f(\lambda)$ instead and we can then rewrite this as $\omega(k) = 2\pi f(2\pi / k).$

You can think of all of dispersion as just this $v(f)$ function and things would be fine. You already know that infinite plane waves seem to travel with velocity $f~\lambda(f),$ and you might be able to “just see” that they do this by having a dependence like $e^{2\pi i [f t - x/\lambda]}$. But then you might sum a bunch of these into a “Gaussian wave packet” with a cluster of related frequencies, $$g(x, t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm df~e^{-\alpha (f - f_0)^2}~e^{2\pi i [f~t - x/\lambda(f) ]},$$ and ask how that moves.

If the factor $\alpha$ is large, so that the envelope Gaussian curve clusters this strongly around some frequency $f_0$ then we would be able to assume that we could Taylor-expand $$\frac{1}{\lambda(f)} \approx \frac1{\lambda(f_0)} - \frac{\lambda'(f_0)}{[\lambda(f_0)]^2}~(f-f_0),\\
g(x, t) \approx e^{2\pi i~(f_0 t - x/\lambda_0)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm df~e^{-\alpha (f - f_0)^2}~e^{2\pi i (f - f_0)[t + x \lambda'/\lambda_0^2 ]}.
$$ This last expression can then be directly solved for, with a bit of effort. One finds $$g(x, t) = e^{2\pi i~(f_0 t - x/\lambda_0)} ~ e^{\pi^2 (t + x \lambda'/\lambda_0^2)^2 / \alpha}.$$
Note that there are two completely different things going on here. There is the thing that you are absolutely expecting, which is that first half: some pulse oscillating in circles at frequency $f_0$.

But there is the thing that you are probably not expecting, which is that second half: the oscillating wave is contained in a Gaussian amplitude envelope which is traveling with speed $$ v_\text{g} = \frac{-\lambda_0^2}{\lambda'_0} = \left(\left[\frac{\mathrm d\phantom f}{\mathrm df}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda(f)}\right)\right]_{f=f_0}\right)^{-1}. $$

If we instead assume that $\lambda(f)$ has an inverse so that we can define $\omega(k)$ this expression becomes simple to remember because it says instead,

1. A plane wave travels with velocity $v_\text{phase} = \frac{\omega}{k},$
2. A Gaussian wave packet has an envelope which travels with velocity $v_\text{group} = \frac{\mathrm d\omega}{\mathrm dk}.$

You also get a few other freebies; in particular in quantum mechanics you will discover that the dispersion relation for individual massive particles is actually $\omega = \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}$ and therefore the particle's velocity is its group velocity $\hbar k/m,$ agreeing with the definition $p = \hbar k$ for the De Broglie wavelength... I think every quantum mechanics class has someone who makes this mistake of calculating $\omega/k = p/(2m)$ instead and says “wait, where did the other half of the velocity go?.”

Answer (score 2):

If you have a point and you are standing at the point, when a wave passes through you will see $f$ number of waves (peaks and throughs) pass through the point in some time, say $t$. The wavelength tells you the distance between two consecutive peaks (or throughs, depending on how you want to define wavelength). Throughout this answer, we assume that you can somehow change the wavelength. If the distance between two peaks increase, less waves will pass through the point in the same amount of time $t$. When the distance between two peaks reduces, more waves pass through the point in the same amount of time, $t$. The number $f$ is called the frequency of the wave.

You can also think of frequency as the number of waves that fit in a given length (technically a snapshot in time). When the distance between the peaks increases, fewer whole waves can be accommodated in that space. Decrease the wavelength and more waves could be accommodated in that space. Therefore, $f(\lambda)$.

Comment: What you describe is $v=\lambda f$.  I think that's different that what the OP is asking about:  $v(\lambda) = \lambda f(\lambda)$.  That is, the frequency changes with wavelength for some reason *other* than its relationship with velocity.

Comment: @garyp I never mentioned velocity. Speed does not factor into my explanation, only distance and number of waves passing through a point do.

Comment: Sorry if I misinterpreted.  But if I did, others will, too.  "When the distance between two peaks reduces, more waves pass through the point in the same amount of time, " sounds like velocity.  But your answer includes velocity as one cause of changing frequency, while the OP is specifically talking about cases where the frequency is is a function of wavelengths for reasons other than velocity.

Comment: There is a difference between 'number of waves crossing a point in $t$ ', and 'distance travelled in $t$'. If I can throw 100 darts in 1 seconds, that does not mean that the speed of the dart is 100 m/s. That's where you are having trouble understanding. _Number_ of waves is frequency, but distance travelled by waves is velocity.

Comment: You don't make the point that you are allowing the wavelength to change.   You don't say that it can't, either.   I think you can clean this up to make it less ambiguous.  You give a nice intuitive way to think about this but your presentation could be clearer, and perhaps an explicit mention of how this relates to the OP.   Things left unsaid go even better when said.

Answer (score 2):

"Dispersion occurs when pure plane waves of different wavelengths have different propagation velocities, so that a wave packet of mixed wavelengths tends to spread out in space. The speed of a plane wave, v, is a function of the wave's wavelength $\lambda$"

The differential equation of a  wave  is:

$$\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2}=v(\lambda)^2\,\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}\tag 1$$

with the Ansatz :

$$A(t,x)=A_0\,\sin(\omega(\lambda)\,t-k\,x)$$

you obtain: equation (1)

$$v(\lambda)^2=\frac{\omega(\lambda)^2}{k^2}$$

with :

$\omega(\lambda)=2\,\pi\,f(\lambda)\quad $ and $k=\frac{\lambda}{2\,\pi}$

thus:

$$\boxed{v(\lambda)=\lambda
\,f(\lambda)}$$

**edit**

$$\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial t^2}={\it A_0}\,\sin \left( -\omega\,t+kx \right) {\omega}^{2}$$

$$v^2\,\frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial x^2}=v^2\,{\it A_0}\,\sin \left( -\omega\,t+kx \right) {k}^{2}$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$\omega^2=v^2\,k^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$v(\lambda)=\lambda f(\lambda)$ is usually written $V=\lambda F$, so $F=V/\lambda$.

So your statement "The function f(λ) tells us that the frequency of a wave depend solely on its wavelength" is wrong. Frequency depends on the propagation speed and the wavelength.

If the wave is a E/M wave then $V=c$, a constant, and the statement would be true.

Comment: I think that's different that what the OP is asking about:  $v(\lambda) = \lambda f(\lambda)$.  That is, the frequency changes with wavelength for some reason *other* than its relationship with velocity.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about waves.

In the real world, waves are created by something that moves back and forth for awhile, and then it quits. That is, things are mostly wavelets. When we talk about waves, we are talking about something that keeps oscillating back and forth long enough that it makes sense to think about it continuing, and we can spend at least part of the time ignoring the startup and the wind-down.

We think about a wave having a constant velocity and a constant wavelength. Something that fits a sine wave is easy to think about. You can look at the sine wave at one point and over time the value at that point increases and decreases. Or you can look at the sine wave at one time, and its peaks and troughs are laid out.

If the speed is constant and the wavelength is constant from one peak to the next, then the frequency has to be constant too. Because the frequency IS the number of peaks that pass in a unit of time, and if they are passing at constant speed....

Once we decide that it is a wave we're talking about, with equally spaced peaks that each travel at the same constant speed, there isn't anything left to influence the frequency except the distance between peaks. It's inherent in the things we said were true.

The real situation could be more complicated. For example, if you don't know the direction the wave is actually traveling, if you think it's some other direction, then you will measure the right frequency (because you can't wrongly count the number of peaks that pass you). But your idea of the wavelength and the speed will be wrong, and their errors will cancel just right to get you the right frequency. But you'll still get the right results according to your assumptions.